# Able to create a map with strings as keys but when the key is referred it gives "Unexpected number error"

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Please look into the code snippet below:

```
var arr = [{"id":"123", "name":"Jyotirmoy"}];
var mapObj = {};
for(var  i=0; i < arr.length; i++){mapObj[arr[i].id] = arr[i];}
```

Now the map is created but when I try to refer it with the key like:

mapObj.123 it gives me a "Unexpected number" error? But if I try the same with mapObj[123] or mapObj["123"] it shows me the correct object. What do I need to do to refer the same using the '.' notation?

Comment: If the `id` values weren't numeric, you could access them via `.`-notation. Since they *are*, you need to use `[]` notation, as you've seen.

Comment: Basically like Paul mentioned, the syntax for variables names applies for property names when you attempt to access them as such `var.prop`. So they cannot start with a digit.

Answer (score 1):

> What do I need to do to refer the same using the '.' notation?

In this case, you can't.

When using the [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), the property's name must be a valid [identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier):

> In JavaScript, identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters (or "$" or "_"), and **may not start with a digit.**

So, to access a numeric key, like `123`, you'll have to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```
myObj[123]
```

---

If you're rather determined to use dot notation, adding an alpha prefix to the keys would permit its use:

```
var arr = [{"id":"123", "name":"Jyotirmoy"}];
var mapObj = {};

for(var  i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
  mapObj['id_' + arr[i].id] = arr[i];
}

console.log(myObj.id_123);
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript properties, when accessed via dot notation (`a.x`) can't begin with a digit.

If the object was

```
{ one1: foo }
```

then

```
mapObj.one1
```

would work.  Since the `id` values *are* numeric, you need to use bracket notation (`a[x]`):

```
mapObj[1]
```

or

```
mapObj["1"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
var arr = [{"id":"123", "name":"Jyotirmoy"}];
```

To

```
var arr = {"id":"123", "name":"Jyotirmoy"};
```